# Tooltips with images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I'm playing around with [tooltips of jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/). But, instead of a text, I want an image to be displayed. Also, the image depends on the text I hover.

I have a list with some numbers, all of the same class:

```
<a class="images" href="#" title="">Number 0</a>
<a class="images" href="#" title="">Number 1</a>
<a class="images" href="#" title="">Number 2</a>
```

When I hover over the second link, an index (in this case 1) should be passed to the function, so that the number 1 will be shown.
But, how can I pass the index to the function?

This is my temporal solution:

```
var number = 1; // only a temporal solution

$(".images").tooltip({
  content: '<img width="100" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iconarchive/red-orb-alphabet/256/Number-' + number + '-icon.png" />'
});
```

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vdtvews6/).

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through the images using $.each and then lookup the number from the element HTML.

```
$('.images').each(function() { 
    var number = $(this).html().replace('Number ', '');
    $(this).tooltip({
        content: '<img width="100" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iconarchive/red-orb-alphabet/256/Number-' + number + '-icon.png" />' 
    });
});
```

Updated fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/vdtvews6/1/

Comment: that work..but if text is changed then your code will  not work..See Link : http://jsfiddle.net/patelsumit5192/uzoqd9bh/

Answer (score 0):

> Notes: Add Custom attribute " number "

**Update Your Html**

```
<a class="images" href="#" title="" number="1">Number 1</a>
<br /><br />
<a class="images" href="#" title="" number="2">Number 2</a>
<br /><br />
<a class="images" href="#" title="" number="3">Number 3</a>
```

**Script**

```
$(document).on('mouseenter','.images',function()
{
    var number = $(this).attr('number');
   $(this).tooltip({
    content: '<img width="100" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iconarchive/red-orb-         alphabet/256/Number-' + number + '-icon.png" />'
}); 

});
```

[Demo In Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/patelsumit5192/nojcht0b/)